# Regex for getting only the last N numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've being trying to generate a regex for this string:

- case1: test-123456789 should get 56789
- case2: test-1234-123456789 should get 56789
- case3: test-12345 should fail or not giving anything

what I need is a way to get only the last 5 numbers from only 9 numbers

so far I did this:

```
 case.match(/\d{5}$/)
```

it works for the first 2 cases but not for the last one

Answer (score 7):

You may use

```
/\b\d{4}(\d{5})$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tqeWly/1). Get Group 1 value.

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary (to make sure the digit chunks are 9 digit long) - if your digit chunks at the end of the string can contain more, remove `\b`
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `(\d{5})` - Group 1: five digits
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['test-123456789','test-1234-123456789','test-12345'];
var rx = /\b\d{4}(\d{5})$/;
for (var s of strs) { 
  var m = s.match(rx);
  if (m) { 
     console.log(s, "=>", m[1]);
   } else {
     console.log("Fail for ", s);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var test="test-123456789";
console.log((test.match(/[^\d]\d{4}(\d{5})$/)||{1: null/*default value if not found*/})[1]);
```

This way supports default value for when not found any matching (look at inserted comment inline above code.).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookbehind `(?<=  )` to assert that your group of 5 digits is preceeded by a group of 4 digits without including them in the result.

`/(?<=\d{4})\d{5}$/`

```js
var inputs = [
"test-123456789", // 56789
"test-1234-123456789", // 56789
"test-12345", //fail or not giving anything
]

var rgx = /(?<=\d{4})\d{5}$/

inputs.forEach(str => {
  console.log(rgx.exec(str))
})
```